# Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" generates empty proxy, but Add Web Reference generates proxy correcly

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, visual-studio, proxy

Consider following URL:

http://mahanair.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

When I use **Add Service Reference**, it generates an empty C# file, but when I use **Add Web Reference**, it finds 7 data sets & 1 service, and generates C# code for them !

Note: Add Service Reference will generate C# code based on **Service Model Client**, but the old "Add Web Reference" uses the old approach (**SoapHttpClientProtocol**)

I really need that ServiceModel client one.

What's a problem here ?

Note:
I've unchecked 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'.

Comment: I tried to add it in VS 2012, but it appears there are issues with the WSDL - one error stating code failed to generate, and then 100+ warnings about ports and missing schemas.  Not sure why it works with ASMX.

Comment: Have you tried using wsdl.exe?

Comment: @TomRedfern Yes, I've had tested wsdl.exe.

Comment: @Tim I can not understand what's going on )-:, but I'm going to test that service in Java application client. Main features are working in ASMX version, but it has its own problems, for example some properties are missing ! I'll add more details to my question tomorrow.